# URL-based rules for Google Translate in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, translation

When using the translation feature in Chrome, and upon visiting a foreign web page, there are three options granted:

1. Always translate the language
2. Never translate the language
3. Never translate the **web page**

A fourth option, which is to ALWAYS translate the **web page**, is eerily missing.

Is there any way to configure Chrome to always translate a specific web page?

While it is possible to always translate a language and then blacklisting specific websites, I find it a lot more tedious and it would require many additional clicks to get things right.
Having some sort of a Chrome URL-based "whitelist" (that is user-configurable of course) of always-translated web pages would be great.

While I do frequently use the translation feature when visiting foreign websites, some websites are viewed better in their original language, and regardless I rather always view the page in its original formatting before I translate it.

Thanks a lot!